# Retreive result of a query and copy it to excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create a macro that basically goes into a website, introduces two pieces of information which are required and than copies the result of the query back to my excel.

As I lack some skills in macros i did this by simply "recording macro". Everything worked out except for 2 things:

1. I get a warning that the website might not be secure which i have to accept manually
2. The part of copying the result of the search simply copies the result of the search which I did in the first place, it does not change to accomodate different search parameters.

As a aid, the website is https://ovc.catastro.meh.es/ovcservweb/ovcswlocalizacionrc/ovccoordenadas.asmx?op=Consulta_CPMRC

And the values i want to introduce are:

SRS: EPSG:4230
RC: 9559313CF7695N

The SRS will be the same in all "searches" yet the RC will change (will have around 2000 RCs to introduce)

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("A3").Select
Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
Range("D3").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C3").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("E3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "<consulta_coordenadas xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns=""http://www.catastro.meh.es/"">" & Chr(10) & "<control>" & Chr(10) & "<cucoor>1</cucoor>" & Chr(10) & "<cuerr>0</cuerr>" & Chr(10) & "</control>" & Chr(10) & "<coordenadas>" & Chr(10) & "<coord>" & Chr(10) & "<pc>" & Chr(10) & "<pc1>9236807</pc1>" & Chr(10) & "<pc2>YK3293N</pc2>" & Chr(10) & "</pc>" & Chr(10) & "<geo>" & Chr(10) & "<xcen>-0.2006669898936</xcen>" & Chr(10) & "<ycen>39.9282269230232</ycen>" & Chr(10) & "<srs>EPSG:" & _
    "4230</srs>" & Chr(10) & "</geo>" & Chr(10) & "<ldt>CL CONCILI VATICA II (DEL) 26 BETXI (CASTELLÓN)</ldt>" & Chr(10) & "</coord>" & Chr(10) & "</coordenadas>" & Chr(10) & "</consulta_coordenadas>" & _
    ""
Range("E3").Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
```

End With
End Sub

[This is a picture of my excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAnG8.png)

Thank you
[Macro attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZehQ.png)